# Authenticate to InfluxDB from Grafana - Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, grafana, influxdb

I have the following scenario:

- InfluxDB is deployed to Azure App Service and running as a Linux Container. It's pulled from the DockerHub in the App Service Container Settings.
- Grafana is also deployed to Azure App Service and running as a Linux Container. And it's also pulled from the DockerHub in the App Service Container Settings. Azure AD login is configured on the Grafana App using Grafana's relevant Env. variables.

After this it's a straight forward integration to add InfluxDB as a data source in Grafana.

However, there is now a requirement for the InfluxDB Web App to be AAD authenticated - therefore, I have the AAD authentication configured in the App Service -> Authenticaton/Authorization section in Azure. Obviously, adding the InfluxDB app as a data source returns 401 because there's an AAD authentication.

I was wondering if there's any way to generate a JWT token and pass it to the InfluxDB. This is where I get a bit out of my depth as I am relatively new to Grafana and InfluxDB.

I read about the [plugin authentication doc](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/plugins/add-authentication-for-data-source-plugins/) but wasn't sure how to progress with this.

Is what I am trying to achieve even possible? I appreciate any pointers / help on this.

Thank you!